# Как с помощью CSS Grid централизировать внутри блока loginContainer блок loginForm?

Tags: css-grid

```
<div className = {style.loginContainer}>
     <div className = {style.loginForm}>
           <h1 className = {style.title}>LOGIN</h1>
           <LoginReduxForm 
               onSubmit = {onSubmit}
           />
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте у родительского компонента стиль:

```
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Вот [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/digital-ecosystems/blog/321244/) подробно рассказано про flex

Comment: Вопрос же про grid был, вроде, не?

Comment: @humster_spb Да, накосячил. Гридом не знаю как. Не пользуюсь

Comment: я вот сам флексом могу, а гридом чет никак. Не могу найти нигде подобной реализации(

Comment: @Rostislav А зачем? Какой смысл?

Comment: @hedgehogues нужно централизировать форму логинизации (по центру экрана)

Comment: Если говорить про решение задачи, то кажется, что флекс с этим отлично справляется. Если говорить про решение вопроса, то я затрудняюсь ответить, к сожалению